# How to create a proxy to access an external API?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cors, create-react-app

I am trying to access an API with my react application. Specifically, I am trying to access the IGDB API. Since I am getting CORS errors, I am trying to set up a proxy as mentioned on their website: https://api-docs.igdb.com/#cors-for-js-ionic

I am unable to set up this proxy to get bypass this. Would something like AnyProxy work?

Comment: Are you trying to access an external api on a dev environment? If you are, you can add a proxy field to your package.json and that'll avoid CORS issues. More info found here - https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development

Comment: What domain would I put under this proxy parameter? I am trying to access https://api-v3.igdb.com/games

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question drove me crazy. I decided to [CORS Anywhere.](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere) Essentially, you use it as a gateway between your development environment and the public API you are trying to consume. For me doing this: `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api-v3.igdb.com/games/?search=Halo`

was the solution to my error.

Comment: I refuse to believe this is the only solution. Crazy!

Comment: This method has security risks, as it is public

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on my comment on proxy here for better view.

Here's an example of how that might look like.

package.json

```
{
 "proxy": "http://api-v3.igdb.com"
}
```

fetch.js

```
function fetchGames() {
 fetch('/games')
}
```

Comment: Whenever I do this, it still tries to send through `localhost:3000`

Comment: Have you tried rebuilding your project?

Comment: @Lewis Was your problem solved?

Comment: Hi Shawn, thanks for the reply. My solution was to use cors-anywhere. That way it was easy for me to test in development.